# Count icosahedron edge colorings

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

How many ways are there to color the edges of an icosahedron in five colors so that any two adjacent edges have different colors? Equivalently, any vertex has incident edges of all five colors.
The answer is given in the article at Mathpages (http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath095.htm), however, the author does not describe in detail how they have arrived at it. My guess is that it was done by exhaustive computer search.
I wonder, are there more clever solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you considered the automorphism group of the icosahedral graph?